# Existence of categorical quotient $X/\mathbb{G}_{m,A}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory, group-schemes

Let $A$ be an $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$-Algebra of finite type (one might assume $A$ to be reduced). Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}_A^d\backslash \{0\}$ be a closed $A$-subscheme together with a group action of $\mathbb{G}_{m,A}$ induced from the action on $\mathbb{A}_A^d\backslash \{0\}$. Under those assumptions, does there exist a categorical quotient $X/\mathbb{G}_{m,A}$ which is a finite type scheme over $A$?

I think this should work in the case $A= \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, as $\mathbb{G}_{m,A}$ is then linearly reductive. But I know too few (references) for more general $A$-group scheme actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take this to be the image of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}_A^{d - 1}$.

To express the above comment about "image" in more precise terms, since for any ring $A$ at all the natural map$$\pi: \mathbb{A}_A^d - \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}_A^{d - 1}$$is a $\mathbb{G}_{m, A}$-torsor, a closed subscheme $X$ of $\mathbb{A}_A^d - \{0\}$ is $\mathbb{G}_{m, A}$-stable if and only if the associated ideal sheaf is stable under the descent datum for $\pi$. Hence, descent theory for quasicoherent sheaves provides a unique closed subscheme $Z \subset \mathbb{P}_A^{d - 1}$ over which $X$ is a $\mathbb{G}_{m, A}$-torsor and it is the desired "quotient" of $X$ (over $A$) in all good senses.

Comment: Sorry for asking further, but when you say "in all good senses", do you actually mean "in all good senses"? I.e., what is needed for $Z$ to be a fppf-quotient/geometric quotient? For example $V(x^2+y^2) \subset \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ is not a geometric quotient of $V(x^2+y^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ I think.